# Cosmos DB read call

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I'm making a call to Azure Cosmos DB where I know the data I'm querying does NOT exist.

I was expecting to get a `null` value but instead I'm getting:

> Enumeration yielded no results

[image]

How do I test whether I received a value or not? I was testing for `null` which doesn't work because the outcome is not null.

My code looks something like this:

```
var result = await _client.ReadQuery<myObject>(AccountsCollection, sql, pa);
if(result == null)
   return null;
```

Comment: Check for `.Any()` in addition to `null`:  `if(result == null || !result.Any())`

Comment: Still skipping the line where I check for `null` or `Any()`. I think it has something to do with the `async` call. I guess I'm getting a promise not a result.

Comment: Well 2 things, use `var` only when the type is obvious (i.e var foo = new DateTime()).  Also, make sure your any logic matches what I put in the comment above.  If result is null OR result does NOT have any

Comment: Also, it looks like you are using `HttpClient` to read from Cosmos instead of the Cosmos library.  Any reason for that?

Comment: Sorry, it does work! I didn't use the "not" i.e. `!` before `Any()`. I am using Cosmos DB library. I'm not using `HttpClient`. I placed my Cosmos DB logic in a different class which I called `_client` which is only a wrapper around Cosmos DB library. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just checking on `result == null` you should use the LINQ extension method `.Any()` to see if there are any items that match a condition (in your case the condition is just *anything* existing in the collection):

```
if(result == null || !result.Any())
{
    return null;
}
```